# LoopBack Model Definition vs json-schema

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, jsonschema, apiconnect

Newbie: Trying to better understand how [Loopback Model Definition](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file) relates (if at all) to [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html). Will I be able to just write a json-schema file and use that as the Loopback Model Definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are definitely *some* close similarities between the two, `json-schema` and `LoopBack`'s model definition are not the same.

If you have existing JSON schemas, you can probably convert those to LoopBack model definitions, but depending on how complex / advanced your schemas are will determine how easy that conversion is.

Comment: Does a tool exist to go from json-schema to LoopBack Model Definition or LMD to json-schema?
Will the team move closer to using json-schema since Swagger 2.0 is based on json-schema?
Thanks for the information...

Comment: Looks like someone wrote a mechanism for using json-schema within LoopBack: https://github.com/backstage/loopback-jsonschema. YMMV. I don't have any information about the future of LoopBack's model definition, sorry. You could look through their issues on GitHub here and open one about this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues